# **How to retrieve Running application CPU usage programmatically?** : Android

Tags: android, cpu-usage

How to retrieve Running application sizes, CPU usage programmatically?

is it possible or not.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
private float readUsage() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
        String load = reader.readLine();

        String[] toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
              + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(360);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        reader.seek(0);
        load = reader.readLine();
        reader.close();

        toks = load.split(" ");

        long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
        long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
            + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

        return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i use this but i am confused what it returns is it total cpu usage or running app cpu usage and onmor thing is mb or kb

Comment: it returns mb or kb and can we find individual running applications cpu usage

Comment: @saritha  have u successfully found individual running applications cpu usage can u pls tell how u calculate ?

Comment: It returns 0 to me always